# Object element from XML De-serialization not filling Attributes are

Tags: c#, xml, class, xml-deserialization

I am receiving back from a Web Service XML that looks like this:

```
<RESULT>
<GRP ID="INP">
    <FLD NAME="SORDNO" TYPE="Char"></FLD>
    <FLD NAME="SITENO" TYPE="Char">999</FLD>
</GRP>
<TAB DIM="100" ID="POS" SIZE="0"/>
<TAB DIM="500" ID="ERR" SIZE="2">
    <LIN NUM="1">
        <FLD NAME="ERRORS" TYPE="Char"/>
    </LIN>
    <LIN NUM="2">
        <FLD NAME="ERRORS" TYPE="Char">Site code 999 is not valid</FLD>
    </LIN>
</TAB>
```

I want to codify the XML into an object so I created a class that seems to match the XML structure:

```
namespace DropShipmentFulfillment.SagePOCreateProcess
{
    public class SagePOCreateResponse1
    {
        [XmlRoot("RESULT")]
        public class RESULT
        {
            [XmlElement("GRP")]
            public RESULTGRP GRP;
            [XmlElement("TAB")]
            public RESULTTAB[] TAB;
        }
        public partial class RESULTGRP
        {
            [XmlAttribute("ID")]
            public string ID;
            [XmlElement("FLD")]
            public RESULTFLD[] FLD;
        }
        public partial class RESULTTAB
        {
            [XmlAttribute("DIM")]
            public string DIM;
            [XmlAttribute("ID")]
            public string ID;
            [XmlAttribute("SIZE")]
            public string SIZE;
            [XmlElement("LIN")]
            public RESULTLIN[] LIN;
        }
        public partial class RESULTLIN
        {
            [XmlAttribute("NUM")]
            public string NUM;
            [XmlElement("FLD")]
            public RESULTFLD FLD;
        }
        public partial class RESULTFLD
        {
            [XmlAttribute("NAME")]
            public string NAME;
            [XmlAttribute("TYPE")]
            public string TYPE;
        }
    }
}
```

When I perform the serialization I execute this code:

```
private SagePOCreateResponse1.RESULT GetPOResponse(SageWeb.CAdxResultXml sageSvcResponse)
{
    string xml = sageSvcResponse.resultXml;

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SagePOCreateResponse1.RESULT));
    StringReader rdr = new StringReader(xml);
    SagePOCreateResponse1.RESULT resultingMessage = (SagePOCreateResponse1.RESULT)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
    return resultingMessage;
}
```

When I execute the program I do not get an error indicating that the class structure does not match the XML structure, but specifically, the FLD element does not contain a value.  For example, if I stop to take a look at a specific field (FLD), in GRP I get the attributes values but not the value of the element:

```
?objectResponse.GRP.FLD[0]
{DropShipmentFulfillment.SagePOCreateProcess.SagePOCreateResponse1.RESULTFLD}
    NAME: "SORDNO"
    TYPE: "Char"
```

It seems like the serializer is not putting the element value in place though I think I have named it right and I get no errors.

**What am I missing?**  Why would it resolve the attributes and not the element values?

I did try doing the XSD creation to C# Class route, but when I had to deal with dynamic lines (LIN) I tried creating my own class.

Comment: You only have attributes and classes.  You are missing the innertext.  Use following :             [XmlText]
            public string value;

Comment: I did try that and it did not work.  I still do not get a value from the innerText.  I am still trying to make this work before I switch back to parsing via the DOM.

Comment: You have an array.  The are two types of Xml Arrays 1) One level of tags 2) Two Levels of Tags. You are using :  [XmlElement("FLD")] which means the Xml File has only one level of tags for the array.

Comment: Yes though the issue was not so much the array but how I defined the FLD value.  When I put this in place I was able to get the Value from the XML:

        public partial class RESULTFLD
        {
            [XmlAttribute("NAME")]
            public string NAME;
            [XmlAttribute("TYPE")]
            public string TYPE;
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
            public string Value;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jdweng I was able to find a solution.  Keeping all things the same from my question I changed one class:

> ```
>     public partial class RESULTFLD
>     {
>         [XmlAttribute("NAME")]
>         public string NAME;
>         [XmlAttribute("TYPE")]
>         public string TYPE;
>         [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
>         public string Value;
>     }
> ```

I needed this line "[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]" instead of just the "[XmlText]" line.

The class now deserilizes the XML so I get both attribute values and innerText values.